# python regex, capturing a pattern with trimming repeated subpattern in string

Tags: python, python-re

Here is a list of input strings:

```
"collect_project_stage1_20220927_foot60cm_arm70cm_height170cm_......",
"collect_project_version_1_0927_foot60cm_height170cm_......",
"collect_project_ver1_20220927_arm70cm_height170cm_......",
```

These input strings are provided by many different users.
Leading "collect_" is fixed, and then follows "${project_version}" which doesn't have hard rule to set this variable, the naming will be very different by different users.
Then, there will be repeating "${part}${length}cm_.......", but the number of repeatence is not fixed.

I'd like to capture the the variable ${project_version}.
Then, I try using the following re.match to capture it.

```
re.match(r'collect_(.*)_(?:(?:foot|arm|height)\d+cm_)+.*' , string)
```

However, the result is not as expected.

Is there anyone give me a hint that what's wrong in my regular expression?

Comment: Why do you have `\*` at the end? There's no `*` in the string.

Comment: What *is* the result? I'm guessing it returns `None` (since as @Barmar notes, there is no literal `*` in the string, though your trailing ellipsis of dots might mean there *is* a literal `*` you omitted), but a [MCVE] needs to include not just the input, but the expected output *and* the observed behavior.

Comment: Hi Barmar, sorry, It's just a typo.

Comment: @RichardZheng: Please edit the code to fix that and make sure there aren't any other typos. A difference of a single character can completely change the meaning of a regex.

Comment: If you only want the capture group at the beginning, there's no need for `.*` at the end.

Comment: Do you need `regex` at all? Can you extract the substring by slicing e.g. `project_str = input_str[8:31]`?

Comment: @JackDeeth: I'm not a fan of suggesting magic numbers, and the regex presumably confirms that the string is formatted in the expected way (it requires the leading `collect_` and at least one `cm_` suffixed thing). It's good to confirm your assumptions.

Comment: Hi all, very thanks for your answers. This is my first time to submit question here. I think the original description is not much precisely expressing the issue I encountered. I already added more information to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you were only planning to capture the part preceding the various `cm` suffixed components, the reason you're capturing so many of them instead of just checking and discarding them is that regexes are greedy by default.

You can narrow your capture group to only match what you really expect (e.g. just a name followed by a date), replacing `(.*)` with something like `((?:[a-z]+[0-9]*_)*\d{8})`.

Alternatively, you can be lazy and enable non-greedy matching for the capture group, changing `(.*)` to `(.*?)` where the `?` says to only take the *minimal* amount required to satisfy the regex. The latter is more brittle, but if you really can't impose any other restrictions on the expression for the capture group, it's what you've got.

Comment: Hi ShadowRanger, very thanks for your answer. This is my first time to submit question here. I think the original description is not much precisely expression the issue I encountered. I already added more information to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-greedy quantifier. Otherwise, the capture group will match as far as it can, so it will keep going until the last match for `(?:foot|arm|height)\d+cm_)`.

```
result = re.match(r'collect_(.*?)_(?:(?:foot|arm|height)\d+cm_)+' , string)
print(result.group(1)) # project_stage1_20220927
```

Answer (score 0):

The  regex "(.*)" will capture far too much.

```
re.match(r'collect_([a-z0-9]+_[a-z0-9]+_[a-z0-9]+)_(?:(?:foot|arm|height)\d+cm_)+' , string)
```